# Upload the content of a file into a single value in mariadb/mysql via a client computer

Tags: mysql, file, upload, mariadb

I have the problem with something that feels like a standard task, but unfortunately is not. I want to load the content of a file from a client computer and insert it as a column value on the mariadb server.

- load_file is not an option, since I can't access the file system on the server's computer. It worked, when I had access to the server's file system in the past.
- MySQL Workbench is not an option, as I don't have a client computer with an xwindows running (using CentOS 7) that has network access to the mariadb server. Also the available version of the workbench on my computer with no admin rights might be too old for the target server.
- loading the file content and encoding it e.g. in base64 does not work, since "Argumentlist too long" error
- load file doesn't seem to work - at least it looks to me as if you have submit the content and the command uses tabs and the like to associate the content. The file for example would include tabs as part of the value.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Then you need to write a program that inserts the file as byte stream to your database server.

Comment: *loading the file content and encoding it e.g. in base64 does not work, since "Argumentlist too long" error* Divide the file and update the row by chunks.